# Does restarting jenkins master node also update older plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We restarted our prod jenkins master node recently from aws(i.e. rebooted the machine) and noticed a lot of our jenkins plug-ins were updated and some had version compatibility issues which led to big downtime. Does force restarting master node automatically update the plugins?

Is there a safer way to restart jenkins master node without updating the plugins?

Our master node was have empty disk space issues and we had to manually restart our master node from AWS, which led to bigger problem.